# Generate random number in Bigquery legacy

Tags: random, google-bigquery

I want to get a random 4 digit integer in BigQuery. I tried the classic

SELECT CAST(10000*RAND() AS INTEGER) as number
but it's giving 0

Adding this question as the results might surprise programmers used to CAST doing a TRUNC in most other languages.

```
SELECT word, CAST(round(10000*RAND(1)) AS integer) as rand
FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare]
order by rand
#Sample size needed = 10
limit 10
```

I am getting result as zero
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUuai.png)

Comment: You're ordering by `rand`, so the ten lowest values (all zero) come first.

Comment: How do I get generate distinct random numbers?

Comment: If you truncate to four digits, you can have at most 10,000 distinct random numbers...you need to rethink your approach if the goal is to generate more random numbers than that.

Answer (score 0):

If you need 10 random numbers:

```
SELECT CAST(round(10000*RAND(1)) AS integer) as rand
FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare]
LIMIT 10
```

With #standardSQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT CAST(round(10000*RAND()) AS INT64) as rand
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1,10))
```

[image]

The problem statement is not clear about the goal - but this is how you generate random numbers between 0 and 9999.